# Как сохранить массивы?

Tags: python, база-данных

Я работаю над одним проектом, и хотел реализовать вот такую функцию:

Есть один массив чисел, программа запрашивает новый массив чисел и сравнивает с предыдущим массивом и, при необходимости, выполняет необходимые операции, и сохраняет эти массивы.

Пишу на Python 3. Как предложите это сделать? Это моя первая работа на Python а с базами данных я знаком не так хорошо. Готов к изучению нового, просто не знаю чего.

**UPDATE**

Я хотел просто спросить про возможные способы, а потом уже решить как делать. Вопрос изначально не подразумевался как конкретный, так как я спросил только про один случай сохранения массива.

Я периодически запрашиваю массив и сравниваю его с предыдущим запрошенным массивом. При необходимости выполняются операции, и после массивы сохраняются *куда-то*. Ведение учёта изменений.

Comment: не думаю, что нужна база данных. Обычная сериализация (просто сохранить в файл) решит все вопросы.

Comment: @KoVadim вы подразумеваете pickle?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "сохранить", куда?

Comment: @Kromster программа запускается каждый день и запрашивает массив, сравнивает с вчерашним массивом, выполняет операции, и сохраняет все это

Comment: не конкретные вопросы с со удаляют обычно)

Answer (score 4):

"Встроенная" система хранения данных между запусками программ питона реализована в библиотечном модуле `shelve`. Интерфейс типа словаря, но сохраняется во внешнем файле. Если нужно какое-то "умное" извлечение данных из больших массивов, поиск по ним, операции SQL, тогда уж используйте внешнюю БД, начните с опять-таки с библиотечного модуля sqlite3.

Answer (score 3):

Если используется просто массив чисел, какой смысл от базы данных? Организуйте все в простых файликах (.txt). Если уж хочется подключить базу данных, посмотрите в сторону PostgreSQL (личное предпочтение).

Comment: скажем, я при каждом запросе сравниваю последний массив с предыдущим и у меня должна сохраняться вся таблица запрошенных массивов. не удобнее ли будет сделать бд?

Comment: *"у меня должна сохраняться вся таблица запрошенных массивов"* -- существенные для ответа детали следует в вопрос помещать (не разбрасывайте требования по комментариям)

Comment: @Hikik0m0ri, а почему не sqlite3? PostgreSQL ведь нужно устанавливать, настраивать. Да и для простой задачи хранения данных будет пушкой по воробьям.

Comment: @gil9red Рекомендовал PostgreSQL по той причине, что Вы потом эти знания легко сможете применить на реальной работе разработчиком и указав в резюме будет большим плюсом. А sqlite3 никому не сдался по сути, только пет проекты свои пилить...по факту знание sqlite3 не особо нужно, а время будет потрачено. Так лучше потратить его на действительно нужные вещи, которые пригодятся в будущем. Это личное мнение, никак не хочу задеть sqlite3 :)))

Comment: @neomendax мне лично было бы удобнее в .txt но если хотите, сделайте в БД. Просто для практики)) так же этого не было указано в изначальном вопросе.

Comment: @Hikik0m0ri о *"никому не сдался"* : если понимать, что sqlite конкурирует с fopen, а не с postgres, то ясно почему sqlite крайне полезное и популярное ПО.

Answer (score 2):

Для массивов чисел часто используют Pandas. Там есть функции для работы с матрицами, а также можно настроить привязку к базе данных для их сохранности, возможно, к sqlite3.